# How is libsigc included in gtkmm projects?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, libsigc++

In the [gtkmm tutorial hello world example](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.2/sec-helloworld.html.en) the `libsigc++` library is used inside the `helloword.cc` file:

```
#include "helloworld.h"
#include <iostream>

HelloWorld::HelloWorld()
: m_button("Hello World")   // creates a new button with label "Hello World".
{
    // Sets the border width of the window.
    set_border_width(10);

    // When the button receives the "clicked" signal, it will call the
    // on_button_clicked() method defined below.
    m_button.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
                &HelloWorld::on_button_clicked));

    // This packs the button into the Window (a container).
    add(m_button);

    // The final step is to display this newly created widget...
    m_button.show();
}
```

However, `libsigc++` is never included in this file, but still this works correctly. Where does the `sigc` namespace come from?

Edit:
`helloworld.h`:

```
#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H

#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>

class HelloWorld : public Gtk::Window
{

  public:
    HelloWorld();
    virtual ~HelloWorld();

  protected:
    //Signal handlers:
    void on_button_clicked();

    //Member widgets:
    Gtk::Button m_button;
};

#endif // GTKMM_EXAMPLE_HELLOWORLD_H
```

Comment: @Nick - I've added it to the question. The complete files are also shown on the page linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the contents of "gtkmm/window.h"

http://fossies.org/unix/privat/gtkmm-3.6.0.tar.gz/dox/gtk_2gtkmm_2window_8h.html

it includes "sigc++.h"

Answer (score 1):

You can find the include in `main.h`

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/tree/gtk/src/main.hg#n22

which is included from `gtkmm.h`

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/tree/gtk/gtkmm.h#n181